# Liferay 6 : OpenLDAP

Tags: liferay, openldap

How to integrate OpenLDAP in Liferay to incorporate single sign-on feature ?

Looking for input for the same.

Thanks ,
Anil

Comment: Recommending move to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should first check to see if you can use the LDAP Authentication provided by Liferay and see if it is compatible with yours.

If not, you can create your own hook using the plugins SDK and add your own login hook.